# connecting to MongoDB with authentication using pymongo 2.7

Tags: python, mongodb, python-2.7, authentication, pymongo

[![enter image description here][1]][1]Hi im trying to connect to mongoDB via a python code

```
client = MongoClient("mongodb://username:mypassword@localhost/mydatabase-1")
db = client['mydatabase-1']
```

and or

```
connection = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
db = connection['mydatabase-1']
db.authenticate('username', 'mypassword')

uri = "mongodb://username:mypassword@localhost.com/mydatabase-1"
client = MongoClient(uri)
```

but i keep getting the same error without fail

```
ConfigurationError: command SON([('authenticate', 1), ('user', u'CEI'), ('nonce', u'950483ef6634f14'), ('key', u'76f0102585a7571d96dace50d7aca5a6')]) failed: auth failed
```

I am using pymongo 2.7 with python 2.7. I guess this means I'm working with mechanism='MONGODB-CR'

I am able to use these credentials to connect to the MongoDB database using MongoChef (a GUI) and it works perfectly.

I have tried to update the pymongo, and it is at version 2.7 i cant use a higher version because I have python 2.7. I cant find any more solutions online. From what i read on the mongoDB website it should work with mechanism='MONGODB-CR' but not for mechanism='SCRAM-SHA-1' due to being v2.7

have mongodb running using

```
E:\MongoDB\bin\mongod.exe --auth --port 27017 --dbpath E:\Data\db
```

and set up the user using

```
use admin
db.createUser(
  {
    user: "username",
    pwd: "mypassword",
    roles: [ { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" } ]
  }
)
```

UPDATE!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

managed to get pymongo 3.4 working using pip install. But still getting this message

```
runfile('C:/Users/mdb_emr_syn/untitled0.py', wdir='C:/Users/mdb_emr_syn')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-19-2ecc66a5cadd>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/mdb_emr_syn/untitled0.py', wdir='C:/Users/mdb_emr_syn')

  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 866, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 87, in execfile
    exec(compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec'), glob, loc)

  File "C:/Users/mdb_emr_syn/untitled0.py", line 11, in <module>
    connection.yo.authenticate("CEI","Syn12345.")

  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pymongo\database.py", line 1048, in authenticate
    connect=True)

  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 505, in _cache_credentials
    sock_info.authenticate(credentials)

  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pymongo\pool.py", line 523, in authenticate
    auth.authenticate(credentials, self)

  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pymongo\auth.py", line 470, in authenticate
    auth_func(credentials, sock_info)

  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pymongo\auth.py", line 450, in _authenticate_default
    return _authenticate_scram_sha1(credentials, sock_info)

  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pymongo\auth.py", line 201, in _authenticate_scram_sha1
    res = sock_info.command(source, cmd)

  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pymongo\pool.py", line 419, in command
    collation=collation)

  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pymongo\network.py", line 116, in command
    parse_write_concern_error=parse_write_concern_error)

  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pymongo\helpers.py", line 210, in _check_command_response
    raise OperationFailure(msg % errmsg, code, response)

OperationFailure: Authentication failed.
```

any ideas as to why????? thanks guys

Comment: I'm not sure whether it's a typo in your question, but you have a `.` (dot) in your URI password value. If it's a typo, please update your question. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I am totally new in MongoDB, and I've just been through this.

Hope this help for others like me.

```
# version info

mongodb : 3.4.7
python  : 2.7
pymongo : 3.5.1
```

---

In my case, the reason I got `Authentication failed` is that I didn't have any user created in the `db` which I wanted to access.

I can check user with `db.getUsers()` in mongodb shell.

```
> use mydatabase-1
switched to db mydatabase-1
> db.getUsers()
[ ]
```

And it's empty.

So what I learned was :

> After created a `db` and put some `docs` into `collection`, should also `createUser()` for that `db`, than *pymongo* can access.

**In mongodb shell**, continue with the example from original post.

db name: `mydatabase-1`

```
> use mydatabase-1
switched to db mydatabase-1
> db.createUser(
...  {
...    user: "username",
...    pwd: "myPWD",
...    roles: [ { role: "readWrite" } ]
...  }
...)
Successfully added user: { "user" : "username", "roles" : [ "readWrite" ] }
```

And than, **In python**

To access your `db`, do this...

```py
client = MongoClient("mongodb://username:myPWD@localhost:port/mydatabase-1")
db = client['mydatabase-1']
```

Or this

```
connection = MongoClient('localhost', port)
db = connection['mydatabase-1']
db.authenticate('username', 'myPWD')
```

And than, print doc from collection `my_collection_name`

```
cursor = db.my_collection_name.find()
for doc in cursor:
    print doc
```

This should solved `Authentication failed`.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade PyMongo. Just because you're using Python 2.7 doesn't mean you have to use PyMongo 2.7. PyMongo 3.4.0 is the latest release, and it works with all versions of Python.

Comment: when i try to install pymongo 3.4.0 the installation wizzard tells me something like, you do not have python 3.4 installed on your computer..... and then i have to close the wizard......

Comment: I have edited the question to include a photo of what I get when I try to install pymongo 3.4 :)

Comment: also when i try

pip install update pymongo 

it updates to version 2.7